# How to check variable type in one line, inside creation block in C#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a custom Json to Object conversion, as I need to handle one of the JTokens differently depending on if it's a string or an integer. However I'm not sure how to obtain the parsing in a compact and clean way.

Code:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherDataPoint { get; set; }
    }

    public int CreateNewIntIdBasedOnString(string stringId)
    {
        //some code
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyClass> ConvertJArrayToMyObjects(JArray array)
    {
        return array.Select(d => new MyClass() {
            Id = ((JObject)d).GetValue("id") == int ? ((JObject)d).GetValue("id") : CreateNewIntIdBasedOnString((string)((JObject)d).GetValue("id")),
            SomeOtherDataPoint = (string)((JObject)d).GetValue("someOtherDataPoint")
        });
    }
```

`((JObject)d).GetValue("id") == int` isn't a thing, so I need something like `int.TryParse` which work on one line. I could create a method for it, but it seems weird that this isn't common enough that there isn't a standardized way of doing it.

Comment: Are you looking for `JToken.TokenType` perhaps?

Comment: `int.TryParse` works on one line

Comment: I've encountered JSON where some numeric properties are numbers and some are strings. But if *the same property* is sometimes a number and sometimes a string, then ideally you should just fix the JSON.

Comment: @Tc_ are you trying to see if a property value is a number ( `myProp:10`) or if it is a string representing a number (`myProp:"10"`)?

Comment: @Magnetron I'm receiving a string, which in some cases can be parsed to an int, but sometimes can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think trying to keep everything in one expression is the wrong approach -- you end up repeating yourself unnecessarily.

If I'm interpreting what you want correctly, I'd write it as something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> ConvertJArrayToMyObjects(JArray array)
{
    return array.Values<JObject>().Select(d =>
    {
        var id = d.Value<string>("id");
        return new MyClass()
        {
            Id = int.TryParse(id, out var intId) ? intId : CreateNewIntIdBasedOnString(id),
            SomeOtherDataPoint = d.Value<string>("someOtherDataPoint"),
        };
    });
}
```

If you *really* want to stuff it in a single expression, you can (ab)use a `var` pattern:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> ConvertJArrayToMyObjects(JArray array)
{
    return array.Values<JObject>().Select(d =>
        new MyClass()
        {
            Id = d.Value<string>("id") is var id && int.TryParse(id, out var intId) ? intId : CreateNewIntIdBasedOnString(id),
            SomeOtherDataPoint = d.Value<string>("someOtherDataPoint"),
        });
}
```